# Return Value from a Function that stores cookies in an Array

Tags: javascript, cookies

I have this code, that puts all cookies in an Array, then gives me back from a specific cookie a specific value that i want. When i run this through the Chrome console and invoke the varaiable manually it works. But iam not sure how to make it work on an html and i cant make the variable return a value.
As it seems as plain JS the last line needs to be part of the function.

```
function getCookie(name) {
    var pattern = RegExp(name + "=.[^;]*");
    matched = document.cookie.match(pattern);
    if(matched){
        var cookie = matched[0].split('promotionCode=');
        return cookie[1];
    }
}
var sa = getCookie('TrackingTags');
```

Comment: Do you have semicolons after each row? I edited your question and added semicolons. And you use `TrackingTags` when you call function, but inside function you split by `promotionCode=`. Is it true what you want?

Comment: Hi, yes this is correct, i want from a cookie called TrackingTags, that has multiple values i.e. promocode=value1proscon=value2newpromocode=value3.  So i managed to get the script working, but i dont know how i can return only the value of the promocode. As when i request from the cookie the promocode= i get all the rest which i dont want to. I only when the value and there are seperators between the values.

Comment: Here is the code i have change it to:

function getCookie(){
    var pattern = RegExp('TrackingTags' + "=.[^;]*")
    matched = document.cookie.match(pattern)
    if(matched){
        var cookie = matched[0].split('promocode=')
        return cookie[1]
    }
}

Works fine but it doest give me only the one value but all the rest which i dont want to. Can you advise?